# How to add pre-defined list to input autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I want to add certain groups of text do an input field. I couldn't make work the Jquery Autocomplete http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data95

Here is the script tag I'm using on the head with the list

```
    <script>
      $(function() {
        var availableTags = [
          "ActionScript",
          "AppleScript",
          "Asp",
          "BASIC",
          "C",
          "C++",
          "Clojure",
        ];
        $( "#field" ).autocomplete({
          source: availableTags
        });
      });
    </script>
```

And the HTML

```
<div class="searchContainer">
        <form>
            <input id="field" name="field" type="text" />
            <button id="submit" href="#" />
        </form>
</div>
```

Comment: So whats your problem??

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/2e6ee/ nothing wrong in code

Comment: that doesn't work :) it still gives me the searches I've made before as suggestions

Comment: It's working for me, the auto-complete shows up.

Comment: How can I cancel the default autocomplete ?

Comment: From what I understand the default Auto-complete can be cancelled in HTML 5 but there may not be a way to do this reliably in all browsers.  I am surprised that you are getting auto-complete most browsers will only use auto-complete for generic input names for example if the name of your input is username then the browser will remember what previous values you have put into `username` fields and pull them up.  I would recommend changing your `input` name to something really generic (i feel like field is already) one that you have not used before and seeing if you still see the auto-complete.

Comment: you were right Trevor, I've changed the input name and it started to work. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing exactly this code? Or this code in a bigger project? It works also for me in the JSFiddle! 
If you are working with Chrome you can press F12 for the development tools and then go to the console to look if there are any errors regarding JQuery! Other browsers support for sure also a console..